# How to move one div into another across screen with animation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this kind of html structure:

```
<div id="block-1"></div>

   <div id="parent-block">
      <div id="block-2"></div>
        <button>Move block</button>
   </div>
```

The #block-1 is floating to the right-top screen corner.

The #parent-block is floating left-bottom screen corner.

I know I can get coordinates of the block using event object, but how can I move #block-2 into #block-1 with smooth animation without depending on screen size?

I want to move it after clicking button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Maybe this](http://jsfiddle.net/rn5rvmff/1/) could help:

```
var velocity = 1500;

$("button").on("click", function(){
    var pos = $("#parent-block").offset();
    $("body").prepend($("#block-2").detach());
    var move = $("#block-2").css({
        "position": "absolute",
        "z-index": "9999",
        "top": pos.top,
        "left": pos.left
    });
    var block1 = $("#block-1").offset();
    move.animate({
        "top": block1.top,
        "left": block1.left
    }, velocity, function(){
        move.css({"top":"","left":""});
        $("#block-1").prepend(move.detach());
    });
});
```

And it works more than once.

Comment: i upvoted because @washin.. using .detach() it is very important in this case. only animation is not good

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this?

Position #block-2 absolutely using CSS:

```
position:absolute;
```

and then add this to your javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('YOUR_BUTTON_ID').click(function() {
        $('#block-2').animate({
        'top' : "0px",
        'right' : "0px"
        });
    });

});
```

Don't forget to add your button id to the code above.

Answer (score 0):

This will get block2 to block1

```
$("button").click(function(){
    var block1 = document.getElementById('block-1');
    var $block2 = $("#block-2");

    $block2.animate({
        bottom: block1.parentNode.scrollHeight - block1.offsetTop - block1.offsetHeight, 
        left: block1.offsetLeft,
    }, 500);
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/johndm/894L3esq/1/